# Responsive base64 images

Tags: svg, background, base64

How do I scale the following base64 image (a background pattern) with transform:scale() or with other methods so, that the pattern would have the same ratio on screens with different resolutions?

Chrome Dev Tools shows that this is a 4x4 px image.

```
url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAH0lEQVQYV2NkQAX/GZH4/xkYGBhhAmAOSBJEwDkgAQCCrgQEjpMcPgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) repeat
```

I want to use transform:scale() or other methods to define the size of the image in viewport units instead of pixels, so that the pattern would have the same ratio on all screens.

Do I need to transform it into SVG instead?

Comment: I understand it's a background image. In this case you can use background-size

Comment: True that, I just posted it in my own answer. The issue is that now the background pattern is smudgy, not 100% uniform. Maybe because 0.4vw width-height that I have choosen is not a good equivalent for 4px, but it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Now I realize that you have a png not an svg

Comment: Ahaa, maybe that's why it's smudgy, i'll try to convert it into svg and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I realized that it's possible to do something like this:

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(10, 14, 15, 0.60), rgba(10, 14, 15, 0.60) ),url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAH0lEQVQYV2NkQAX/GZH4/xkYGBhhAmAOSBJEwDkgAQCCrgQEjpMcPgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) repeat;
    background-size: 0.4vw 0.4vw;
```

But the background pattern is smudgy, not as uniform.